# Possibility of being relatively prime in picking up two numbers

Tags: probability, number-theory

What is the chance of being relatively prime in picking two numbers up of the $\{1, 2, 3, ..., n\}$?

Obviously the answer will be a function of $n.$

Comment: Let $\rho(n)$ be the chance of picking two coprime numbers from $\{1,\dots, n\}$. Then $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\rho(n)=\frac{6}{\pi^2}.$$

Comment: If $\phi$ is Euler's phi function, then the answer is $$\frac{\sum_{k=2}^n\phi(k)}{\binom{n}{2}}.$$

Comment: Thank you Shaun and "WE Tutorial School" but how can I get these results?

Comment: I tried to simulate this, it does seem to converge to $\frac{6}{\pi^{2}}$, maybe it converges very slowly, how can I know the rate of convergence of such a process ?

Comment: @SagarM  From wikipedia, $$\sum_{k=1}^n \phi(k)=\frac{3}{\pi^2}n^2+O\Big(n(\ln n)^{2/3}\big(\ln(\ln n)\big)^{4/3}\Big).$$  So the convergence is very slow.

Comment: What is the O(  ) notation in above equality ?

Comment: @AmirhosseinDolatkhah https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen thank you so much. I'm sorry about my weakness in mathematics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of ways you can pick 2 number is $\binom{n+1}{2},$ to count how many 2-sets are coprime numbers, check that one if the numbers is greater or equal to the other so we have $$\sum _{d=1}^n \varphi (d),$$
where $\varphi(n)$ is Totient Euler's function. It counts coprime numbers less or equal to $n.$ Take the quotient of them.